# Can't install experimental modules

Tags: 8, migrations

I installed Drupal 8.1.2, but I can't install modules of the category "core (experimental)". No problem with other modules or themes for example. I get no logs and no error message. Hitting the install button just redirects me to the extend page.

I have been able to install Migrate by installing Migrate Plus, which requires Migrate, but this does not solve the issue, in particular not for the other modules in "core (experimental)". Is there anything I have to do to be able to install experimental modules?

Comment: No problems when [testing over here](https://simplytest.me/project/drupal), are you using a fresh drupal install? if not, perhaps a contrib module that you downloaded may be causing the problem.

Comment: It is a fresh install

Comment: try doing it again [over here](https://simplytest.me/project/drupal)

Comment: I don't have problems to install them too, as @NoSssweat. I would follow his suggestion to try on simplytest.me.

Comment: Just tried the sandbox and there it works. Of course... :-/ I think I will go for your advice and try a new installation. Maybe something went wrong.

Comment: Still the same problem... Hoster can't help neither because there are no error messages or log entries.

Answer (score 0):

There's a core issue for failure to install experimental modules (or, more precisely, modules with parentheses in the group name with Suhosin): https://www.drupal.org/node/2665152